# Command to output lines in file in alphabetical order?

Tags: command-line, files, output

I have a file containing one word per line.

How can I print out each line in alphabetical order - ie. the first letter of each word decides the order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sort`.

Example file contents:

```
one
four
eight
nine
thirteen
```

To sort alphabetically:

```
sort filename
```

...which will give:

```
eight
four
nine
one
thirteen
```

If you want go from z-a, then use `sort -r`